# How to change a button icon in a PDF form with iText/C#

Tags: c#, button, itext

I'm trying to retrofit an old C# application that was made using the old Adobe Acrobat API.  One of the features of this application was to change the icon of a button and update the caption of the button as well.  The caption was overlayed on top of the icon.

Currently, I'm using iText 7 and C# to program the application.  I have most of the functionality ready, but I can't figure out how to add a caption and icon to a button.  I was able to figure out how to add a caption and an icon seperately, but when I try to combine the code snippets, the icon seems to cover the caption.

```
PdfButtonFormField button = (PdfButtonFormField)pdfForm.GetField(fieldName);
button.SetImage(tempFileLOGO);

var buttonObj = button.GetPdfObject();
buttonObj.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.MK).Put(PdfName.TP, new PdfNumber((int)PushButtonLayouts.LABEL_OVER));

pdfForm.ReplaceField(fieldName, button);

var fields = pdfForm.GetFormFields();
foreach (var f in fields)
{
    if (f.Key.StartsWith("sign_"))
    {
        f.Value.SetValue(fieldValue);
    }
}
```

This code causes the icon to be placed on the button, but I don't see the caption text (variable name "fieldValue")

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from iText code, if a button has an  image its text is always ignored while the button appearance is generated.

So there is no standard way to do it. 
I can suggest you to modify an image first, adding the needed text over it as it is done in this example https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/best-itext-7-questions-stackoverflow/how-add-text-image

And then set a new one using the setImage method

Comment: Hmm...that's an interesting idea.  I'll see if I can work with that.